# How can I explain source control (Mercurial/Tortoise specifically) to a non-programmer?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, mercurial

Our company uses Mercurial for source control of a Java web application.  It worked so well we started using source control for a bunch of content (PDF files).  For our deployment model this worked amazingly and luckily our graphic designer at the time used to be a web developer and understood source control already.

Now we have replaced that fellow with two strictly for print graphic designers.  They are amazing at what they do but look scared and confused every time we ask them to use source control.  For reference we use Tortoise as we found it was the best option for non-programmers due to its user interface.

Hginit.com is a great way for programmers to learn Mercurial, now how about a website for non-programmers?

Any ideas?

Comment: So... you fired the awesome guy for two cheaper bozos? How mundane.

Comment: I think this'd be a much better question over at [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm surprised they're so scared. Every designer I've ever met at work and in my own family has his or her own complex, multi-copy versioning scheme upon which they totally depend. I've never needed more than "it's just some commands that let you do that but with a single file" and a cheat sheet to sell them.

Answer (score 4):

I would explain to them that it's like making a photocopy of your art project through out it's course. During the time that you are drawing, you can discard what you have done and continue from a previous point in time. You can also see what would happen if you started in a different direction from one of the pictures that you made. You can also give a copy to a friend and tell them that they can finish drawing the trees and sky in the background. Later you can merge both of your efforts and see what it looks like. Your friend can also be taking intermittent pictures while they work on the sky and trees. Think of the possibilities!

Answer (score 1):

You can go back to a previous "save", and check the differences between your "saved" versions. Each time you "save" you can also put a comment, like "first draft" or "implemented changes requested by accounting".

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't think so you need a tutorial to get those graphic designers on board. If you understand repository & source control you can simply guide them...

It's just a way to keep a functional copy `trunk` available for everyone; at a point you might have a working copy `branch` just for you for a specific release and with every release the code is marked as `tag` for reference.

Now the only pieces remain are `check-in` put your work in repository, `update` - download others' work and `checkout` - download repository on your local machine.

This are just one liners which I use to bring aboard the freshers which we have time to time.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this exact conversation with some non-developers, although we are using Git for our project. This summarizes how I approached the topic with them:

1. Explain that version control is not merely "backup".
2. At a high level, explain that it like a big "Undo" button for when multiple files and/or people are involved.
3. Explain that this allows you to "tag" progress (production, public release, subsequent versions) and move forward with confidence, knowing that you can roll the project back to a "last known good" state, if necessary.
4. Decide on a source control workflow and philosophy and tell **everyone** to stick to it! (i.e., when to branch, tag, merge, etc., and how much/how often commits should be)
5. School them in the source control GUI of your choice.

**EXAMPLE:**

Like Adam said, it's like taking snapshots of an art project, but I've also had success using this in music compositions where multiple files are involved:

- DAW project files (Logic Pro, et. al.)
- Project Settings
- Audio pluggins and their settings
- Notes for song lyrics
- Initial rough recordings
- Multiple takes
- Multiple remixes, production, or mastering passes

Sometimes I will create and check out a new experimental branch to try a completely different approach in the song's composition and/or production. This will usually affect multiple items from the list above, but I can move forward with confidence, knowing that if something doesn't work quite right, I can always switch to a "stable" version of the project.

Version control is not just for "source" anymore. It's great for any creative digital project of significant scale!